# For positive semidefinite unit trace $\Gamma$, what is $\{ x \in \mathbb R^N: x^T A x = \text{tr}(A \Gamma) \ \forall A \in\mathbb R^{N \times N} \}$?

Tags: c-star-algebras, symmetric-matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite, von-neumann-algebras

> **My question.**
> Let $N > 1$ and $\Gamma \in \mathbb R^{N \times N}$ be a [positive semidefinite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Definitions) with unit [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Definition).
> Can we describe in a simple manner the following set? $$S(\Gamma) := \{ x \in \mathbb R^N: x^T A x = \text{tr}(A \Gamma) \ \forall A \in \mathbb R^{N \times N} \}.$$

**Some ideas.**

1. We have $S(0) = \{ 0 \}$.
2. For $N = 2$, the set $S(\text{id}_N)$ is empty: for $A = \scriptsize\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ we get that the second component of $x \in \mathbb R^2$ must be either $1$ or $-1$. Analogously for $A = \scriptsize\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ we get that the first component of $x \in \mathbb R^2$ must be either $1$ or $-1$. For $A = \scriptsize\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ we get that $x_1 x_2 = 0$, which is a contradiction.
3. If $x \in S(\Gamma)$, then $c x \not\in S(\Gamma)$ for all $c \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ \pm 1 \}$, so we can think of the $x \in S(\Gamma)$ as directions, the length being fixed.
4. The condition $x^T A x = \text{tr}(A \Gamma)$ is invariant under transposition of $A$, so we have
   $$
   S(\Gamma) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^N: x^T A x = \text{tr}(A \Gamma) \ \forall A = A^\mathsf T \in \mathbb R^{N \times N} \}.
   $$
5. We can explicitly write the condition (where $\Gamma = (\gamma_{j, k})_{j, k = 1}^{N}$) as
   $$
   \sum_{j, k = 1}^{N} a_{j k} x_j x_k
   = \sum_{j, k = 1}^{N} a_{j k} \gamma_{j k} \qquad \forall (a_{j, k})_{j, k = 1}^{N} \in \mathbb R^{N \times N},
   $$
   so if $\Gamma$ has rank 1 and we can thus write it as $\Gamma = x_0 x_0^{\mathsf T}$, then $x_0 \in S(\Gamma)$.
   As $\text{tr}(\Gamma) = 1$, this implies $\| x_0 \| = 1$.

**Background.**
I am reading the first section of [An extension of Kakutani’s theorem on infinite product measures to the tensor product of semifinite *-algebras by Donald Bures](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-135-00/S0002-9947-1969-0236719-2/).
I want to understand definition 1 for the real full matrix [von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Definitions) $\mathcal A := \mathbb R^{N \times N}$.

*Definition 1.*
Let $\mathcal A$ be a von Neumann algebra and $\Sigma$ the set of [normal states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(functional_analysis)#Normal_states) on $\mathcal A$.
A representation $\phi$ of $\mathcal A$ on $H$ we mean an isomorphism of $\mathcal A$ onto a von Neumann algebra acting on $H$.
For $\mu \in \Sigma$ let
$$
S(\phi, \mu)
:= \left\{ x \in H: ( \phi(A) x \mid x)_H = \mu(A) \ \forall A \in \mathcal A \right\}
$$
the set of vectors such that $\mu$ induces a [vector state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(functional_analysis)#Vector_states) of $\mathcal A$ with respect to the representation $\phi$.

---

I chose $H := \mathbb R^N$ and $\phi \colon \mathcal A \to B(H)$, $A \mapsto (x \mapsto A x)$.
Since $\mathcal A$ is finite-dimensional, all states are normal and the state space of $\mathcal A$ is
$$
\mathcal S(\mathcal A)
:= \left\{ A \mapsto \text{tr}(A \Gamma): \Gamma \in S_{+, 1}^N \right\}
\cong S_{+, 1}^N
:= \left\{ X \in \mathcal A: \text{tr}(A) = 1, A = A^{\mathsf{T}} \right\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in S(\Gamma)$. Then for $A=\Gamma-xx^T$, we have
$$
\|\Gamma-xx^T\|_F^2
=\langle A,\Gamma-xx^T\rangle_F
=\operatorname{tr}\left(A(\Gamma-xx^T)\right)
=\operatorname{tr}(A\Gamma)-x^TAx
=0.
$$
Therefore $\Gamma$ is necessarily equal to $xx^T$.

In other words, $S(\Gamma)$ is empty if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(\Gamma)>1$. When $\operatorname{rank}(\Gamma)\le1$, we can express $\Gamma$ as $xx^T$ for some vector $x$. Hence $S(\Gamma)=\{x,-x\}$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Do you know whether all states on $\mathcal A$ are normal as I claimed? And you know if there are other representations of $\mathcal A$? Because on p. 201 of the paper linked above it is stated that there exists a representation such that $S(\phi, \mu) \ne \emptyset$ for all $\mu \in \Sigma$.

Comment: Sorry for asking another question, but do you by any chance know why we need the injectivity of $\phi$ in this construction?

Comment: If you want a rep such that every normal state can be written as a vector state, you should look at the standard form of von Neumann algebras (Haagerup). For general von Neumann algebras this is not so easy, but in the case of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ it's simply the left action on the Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Comment: @Ramanujan Sorry, von Neumann algebra is not really my field, but to my understanding, yes, every vector state on a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra $\mathcal A$ is normal, because normal states are precisely completely additive vector states, and every vector state on $\mathcal A$ is completely additive because every sum of mutually orthogonal projections on $\mathcal H$ is a finite sum. ...

Comment: ...Anyway, you seem to think that a vector state on $\mathbb R^{N\times N}$ is represented by a linear functional of the form $A\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(A\Gamma)$ for some positive semidefinite matrix $\Gamma$ with unit trace, but $\Gamma$ also needs to be rank-one, i.e., $\Gamma=uu^T$ for some unit vector $u$. Then $\phi$ is a matrix congruence.

Comment: @Ramanujan Oh, my bad. I mean $\phi$ is $A\mapsto(x\mapsto P^\ast APx)$ for some unitary $P\in B(H)$. We need $P$ to be not just invertible, but unitary, to make $\phi$ a linear algebra isomorphism and also unit preserving.